# mysqlslap: [ERROR] mysqlslap: Option 'debug-info' used, but is disabled

Tags: mysql

When I use the command mysqlslap like:

mysqlslap --concurrency=50,100,200 --iterations=1 --number-int-cols=5 --number-char-cols=5 --auto-generate-sql --auto-generate-sql-load-type=mixed --engine=innodb --number-of-queries=100 --auto-generate-sql-guid-primary --debug-info

the system gives out the error:
mysqlslap: [ERROR] mysqlslap: Option 'debug-info' used, but is disabled

If I move the option "--debug-info", then everything goes well.

How do I fix this problem?

basic info:

mysql 5.7

redhat el7

I log in the Linux server with SSH protocol.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/14305/18098 was helpful for enabling verbose logging of mysqldump after getting this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this myself - It's strangely/frustratingly difficult to get a definitive answer, but about 98% sure you have to have a version compiled with debugging enabled.

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/compiling-for-debugging.html

> If you have some very specific problem, you can always try to debug
>   MySQL. To do this you must configure MySQL with the -DWITH_DEBUG=1
>   option. You can check whether MySQL was compiled with debugging by
>   doing: mysqld --help. If the --debug flag is listed with the options
>   then you have debugging enabled. mysqladmin ver also lists the mysqld
>   version as mysql ... --debug in this case.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/porting.html for the overview.

Comment: Why isn't this runtime configurable?